# How to compute $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^x}{x^{200}}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to solve this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^x}{x^{200}}$$

The first result is an indetermination of the kind $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ but here applying L'Hopital would be too long, I do not see any substitution by means of equivalent infinitesimals possible and simplifying the limit neither.

How can I solve it? The solution must be $\infty$. Thank you!

Comment: hi! i'm sorry but I think they're different since I'm looking for a method to compute the limit and not theoretically, as I saw in that question. But, you probably know more mathemathics so if you still think so, should I delete the question?

Comment: okay, and sorry for not realising it before! @Typhon

Comment: @Typhon: There are several answers there which don't use L'Hospital. And there's absolutely *nothing* which is more difficult for the general case than for this special case. And if you want special cases, have a look at the [list of linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/55468?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'Hopital rule applied $200$ times leads to
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log 2)^{200} \,2^x}{200!}=\infty$$

Or you can take the logarithm of the limit

$$\log\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x}{x^{200}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\log 2-200\log x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\log 2-200\frac{\log x}{x}\right)=\infty$$

As the log of the limit  is $+\infty$ the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: @Typhon He has a secondary solution. And this site is about learning, so he shared some knowledge that might help the OP, since the OP (arguably erroneously) asserted that the algorithm is too tedious. So there’s actually nothing wrong about it.

Comment: @Typhon Which was provided

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x}{x^{200}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x}{2^{200\log_2(x)}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 2^{x-200 \log_2(x)} = 2^{\lim_{x \to \infty}x-200 \log_2(x)}$$

That limit clearly goes to infinity, so the whole function does as well

Comment: your base is wrong it should be $\log_2$ not $\ln$

Comment: You're right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^x}{x^{200}}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{x\ln2}}{x^{200}}\rightarrow \mbox{(L'Hopital 200 times)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\ln2)^{(200)}e^{x\ln2}}{200!}=\infty
$$